# Block placement at an adGroup level via REST API

Tags: google-ads-api

I see there is a REST API for blocking placements at a customer level.

But I cannot find if there is an API (preferably REST) for blocking at an ad-group level.

[image]

Is it only possible to remove an existing placement, but not blocking for the future as well (like possible at an account level)?

[image]

Blocking at an account level (`"NegativeCriteria"`):
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/rest/reference/rest/v10/customers.customerNegativeCriteria/mutate